# I type text in my box and it moves the more I type

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML I have 3 boxes with text in them just read the text within the first div.

```css
html,
body {
 background-position: fixed;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: auto;
 background-color: #e2e1e0;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
 -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
 -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
 -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
 -ms-user-select: none;       /* IE/Edge */
 user-select: none; 
 z-index: 1;
}


.header{
font-family: 'Poiret One', Arial;
color: black;
font-size: 2em;
border-radius: 10px;
border-color: black;
border-style: 
}

.infodiv {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 300px;
}

.statsdiv {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
  font-family: 'Oswald', Arial;
}

.statsdiv:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.playerdiv {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
  font-family: 'Oswald', Arial;
}

.playerdiv:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.seconddiv {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
  font-family: 'Oswald', Arial;
}

.seconddiv:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
<body>
<center>

<h1 class="header">Heading Placeholder</h1>
<hr>
<!--Statistic's Division-->
<div class="infodiv statsdiv">
<center>
<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><br><p>This first box moves the more I type, it allows me to type up to 3 lines of text but after that it becomes higher in position for example here X X X<p>
</center>
</div>
<!--Player Division-->
<div class="infodiv playerdiv">
<center>
<i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i><h2>This is a current place holder for any text that I plan on putting here in the future. Don't mind this.</h2>
</center>
</div>
<!--Informational Division-->
<div class="infodiv seconddiv">
<center>
<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i><h2>This is a current place holder for any text that I plan on putting here in the future. Don't mind this.</h2>
</center>
</div>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't think it works well but if you could put it in a notepad real quick it should do the problem that I am having. Currently in the HTML I put 3 letter 'X's remove those 3 X's and the problem should be solved. The issue is that it is only letting me add 3 lines of text.

If you do not understand what I am still trying to say please let me know. I only took 1 class of Computer Science in high school a few years ago so it may be pretty ugly :/

Comment: I'm not fully sure I understand the issue. Do you want to have a div of a specific width and height, which doesn't increase in size the more text you put in it? If not, try to explain in words what exactly you want and how you imagine seeing it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS

```
 .infodiv {
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 300px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add  `vertical-align:top;` to your `.infodiv`
i.e.:

```
.infodiv {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```